# AB Testing other factors besides conversion rate

Tags: contingency-tables, ab-test

So I've been learning about AB Testing and have used it to examine the form conversion rate of two different forms. However, I'm curious about testing whether a form with ads will generate more revenue than a site with just a form and no ads.

So the two things I'm comparing:

```
- form with ads
- form with no ads
```

I'm trying to see which produces more revenue.

So traditionally, a test of conversion rates would involve using a chi-square or fishers exact test to examine the values in a contingency table. I'm just not sure how to approach this question when it comes to revenue.

```
           Revenue     Conversions
Site 1 -    $500         100 
Site 2 -    $400         70
```

Is this no different that a tradition ab test of conversion rates?

Or could I just test wether a form made money or not.

```
          made money       made no money
form 1       50                200
form 2       5                 250
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're interested in revenue, it makes more sense to compare the revenue from the 2 sites rather than whether or not they made money.  However, this means you are comparing *distributions* rather than contingency tables, and need different type of statistical test.  One common test of this type is the [t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Unpaired_and_paired_two-sample_t-tests).

However, the t-test assumes that your data are normally distributed, which probably isn't the case in this situation.  You can do a bit better by using a non-parametric test to compare your distributions, such as the [Mann-Whitney U Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U) (also known as the two-sample Wilcoxon test).

In [R](http://cran.r-project.org/), you can do this with the [wilcox.test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html) command.

Comment: would it be possible to get an example in R of how you would set up a Mann-Whitney U Test with the asker's data?  I am in the same situation but can't seem to get a useful result with wilcox.test.

Comment: @bobfet1: I'm assuming the asker has 2 distributions of money, x and y.  From `?wilcox.test` you can see how to run this test.  For example, if the null hypothesis is that the 2 distributions are the same, use `wilcox.test(x, y, mu=0)`.  If the p values is less than 0.05, you can probably reject the null hypothesis and conclude that the means of the 2 distributions are different.

Answer (score 3):

To compare this two forms, you will need the number os users who filled this forms. More precisely, you need a sample from each form where the variables is the amount of money made with the user. Considering $\theta_{1}$ the vector of samples for the form with no ads and $\theta_{2}$, the samples for the form with ads, you can then do a hypothesis test on the sample mean:
$$ H_0: \bar{\theta_1} = \bar{\theta_2}$$
$$H_1: \bar{\theta_1} \neq \bar{\theta_2}$$

Where the test statistic is:
$$
z_0 = \dfrac{\theta_1 - \theta_2}{\sqrt{\dfrac{s_{\theta_1}^2}{n_1} + \dfrac{s_{\theta_2}^2}{n_2}}}
$$
$n_1$ and $n_2$ are the sample sizes, $s_{\theta_1}^2$ and $s_{\theta_2}^2$ are the sample variance.

The null hypothesis is reject if $|z_0| > z_{\alpha/2}$, considering an $\alpha$ level of significance.

Comment: beware that you are assuming here that the data is (approximately) normal distributed ! Additional problem: If a visitor did not made a money, what is the value of this variable ? 0 ? Then the unknown distribution is not continuous anymore, too. If you on the other hand exclude those visitors, then the case of a form which creates less money but more frequently might be lost.

Comment: If the user did not made money, the value is 0. I am assuming that the distribution of the sample average of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are normal based on the [CLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

Comment: What is "sufficiently large" given an unknown distribution with unknown parameters ? CLT should not be used as an excuse for not caring about the distribution ... but maybe it's just me.