# significance test to use for multiple conversions in an A/B test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

What is the proper way to measure significance in an A/B test, when a visitor can potentially "convert" more than once?

I understand a chi-square test or z-test are most often used for A/B testing, but from what I understand that is only if it is categorical, like if a visitor purchased or not.

In my case, customers can purchase multiple times in a test period, and I want to make sure I'm using the right significance test for this.

For example:

```
test A: 800,000 visitors, 50,000 purchases
test B: 45,000 visitors, 2,700 purchases
```

I saw a similar question here, but it was asking about revenue:
[AB Testing other factors besides conversion rate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19507/ab-testing-other-factors-besides-conversion-rate). In my case, should I be using a Wilcoxon test also?